# How to begin with Java Server Side technologies?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-frameworks

I have a good knowledge of PHP. But I also want to learn technologies such as JSP. I have installed Apache Tomcat 6.0 and Eclipse Java EE.

I was looking for JSP tutorials on Google and found that there are several things like JSP, Servlets, Struts, EJB, JSF, etc. I have heard a lot about Struts and JSF that they are very good.

I want to know in what order should I start learning these technologies. (I have good knowledge of Core Java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to start off by learning the basics of Servlets and JSP.  Those are the building blocks for web application frameworks.

I wouldn't spend *too* much time on Servlets beyond an understanding of how they generally work.  Most of the heavy lifting is done by web app frameworks these days.

Once you're familiar with the basics of how Java serves things up as a web page, move on to more sophisticated frameworks such as JSF, Spring Web MVC or Struts.  These frameworks all utilize the MVC design pattern, which you may have used with PHP frameworks (if not, it's a very good principle to learn).  All of those projects are well-documented and have a sizable community.

As a note, I feel that JSF has a steeper learning curve than either Spring or Struts.  If you are that interested in JSF, I recommend looking into the Seam framework, which utilizes JSF but also somewhat simplifies its use.  You can learn JSF+Seam concurrently.

As for books... for JSF, I like *Core JavaServer Faces*.  For Spring, I like *Spring in Action*.

Comment: Another nice book that is worth taking a look at is Expert One-on-One J2EE Development without EJB (http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764558315.html). It is written by Rod Johnson, who created Spring. Many of the principles described there are still good even if it is a 2004 book.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you Head first Servlet and JSP this fantastic book gives you kick start for JSP and Servlet with the Server side knowledge very perfectly.

[Head First Servlets and JSP](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=15wp6fmAy4sC&printsec=frontcover&dq=head+first+jsp+servlets&ei=2FdQS4HWCY3SkgSQ1MiVDQ&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)